# Android Download Manager "Download Unsuccessful"

Tags: android, android-download-manager

This is my first time trying to implement `DownloadManager` and no matter what I try, I always get a notification saying "Download unsuccessful." I've looked at many other SO forums, a few tutorials, and what I have should work. Yes, I've set internet and external storage permissions in the manifest file. And yes, I've given storage permission in the app settings on the phone. I've tried this on both an Android emulator running API 28 and a real phone running the same. Here is the code I have:

```
        String url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4";

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setTitle("title");

        request.setDescription("Your file is downloading");

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, "" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);

        //Enqueue download and save the referenceId
        long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        if (downloadReference != 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it using other url ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya yes, I've tried 3 urls

Comment: only issue is coming on 28?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I haven't tried another API

Comment: did you check your mobile storage space?

Comment: Make sure your server allows you to download the file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue occur due to network security. If You are using un-secure url in above pie API, then it can't execute your url. Check [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic).

> Reason for avoiding cleartext traffic is the lack of confidentiality,
>   authenticity, and protections against tampering; a network attacker
>   can eavesdrop on transmitted data and also modify it without being
>   detected.

Add following in manifest to bypass all security.

```
<application
  android:name=".ApplicationClass"
  ....
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: That was it. I had it added but I hadn't added the url to the test website I was trying to download from. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I spent HOURS trying to get a .apk download to work, and FINALLY this is the answer that explained why it was failing. Thank you!

Comment: Dont use clearTextTraffic in manifest use it in like android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

Answer (score 4):

My Experience on **1/11/2021**, min SDK 19, Target SDK 30

I spent a day on using Download Service and finally it worked.
To sum it up for anyone who wants to try for the first time:

1. Dont't forget to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and INTERNET permissions in Manifest.
2. use requestPermissions() to  grant permission from user.
3. use getExternalFilesDir() instead of getExternalStorageDirectory().
4. If you're downloading from http:// so add usesCleartextTraffic="true" to manifest.